# How do I set multiple values within Asyncstorage

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, asyncstorage

How do I set multiple values within Asyncstorge?.Because I'm trying to set `token` and `user_id` .These are the server response values.
This is how response looks like

**json**

```
{ error: 0,
  data: 'User registered Successfully',
  userData:
   { pwd: 'lmlmlm',
     phone_no: '9898989',
     user_name: '',
     status: 1,
     date: 2018-10-24T07:12:20.656Z },
  user_id: 60,
  token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.' }
```

And in react native I've written like this after user registrtaion.

```
.then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) =>
            {
                console.log(responseData);
                 AsyncStorage.setItem('id_token', responseData.token),
                 AsyncStorage.setItem('user_id', responseData.user_id),
                    Actions.firstScreen();

                    });
```

And in my home page I'm accessing the `token` and `user_id` within `AsyncStorage` as

```
 AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token').then((usertoken) =>{
                this.setState({'id_token' : usertoken});
                console.log(usertoken);
            })
            AsyncStorage.getItem('user_id').then((uid) => {
              this.setState({'user_id': uid});
              console.log(uid);
            })
```

But I'm getting only the token , consoled result of `uid` is getting as null.But when I consoled the `responseData` I've values within it.Please help me

Comment: I don't know if it will be the issue, but I'd be doing the accessing bit like this: `Promise.all([AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token'), AsyncStorage.getItem('user_id')]).then(([id_token, usertoken]) => {
    this.setState({id_token, user_id});
    console.log(id_token, user_id);
});`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Please check this docs at [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#multiset)

So you can use like this:

```js
const items = [['k1', 'val1'], ['k2', 'val2']]
AsyncStorage.multiSet(items, () => {
    //to do something
});
```

Cheer!

Comment: How to use multiget

Answer (score 2):

```
var items = [['k1', 'val1'], ['k2', 'val2']]
AsyncStorage.setItem("KEY", JSON.stringify(items))
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21219757)